# Jest:- TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params'). Error coming in jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I have below component in react. I put in short only

```
export interface EditCertificateProps {
    id:string;
}

export function EditCertificate(props: any) {
 injectStyle();

 const {id} = props.match.params;
 const history = useHistory();
}
```

When I am doing jest testing it is throwing error.

```
const id = '123';
describe('EditCertificate', () => {
    const params = {
        id: '123',
    };
    it('should render successfully', () => {
        const { baseElement } = render(<EditCertificate id={id} />);
        expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

it is throwing error
[image]

from another component this page gets called like below.

```
  <SecureRoute path="/:id/edit" component={EditCertificate} />
```

I changed my testcase like below still error.

```
describe('EditCertificate', () => {
    const props = {
        match: {
            params: 123,
        },
    };
    it('should render successfully', () => {
        const { baseElement } = render(<EditCertificate {...props.match.params} />);
        expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Why _would_ that change fix anything? You still don't have a `props.match` at all, much less one with a `params` property.

Comment: I renamed id to match and sent this .still getting error. ` const { baseElement } = render(<EditCertificate {...params.match} />);`

Comment: That makes even less sense, you're now trying to spread a _string_ as props (which still doesn't itself have a match attribute). You need to know the basics of JSX syntax to render a component in this way. More broadly you need to think about the _context_ that component needs to be rendered in for the hook to work.

Comment: The component under test is accessing a `props.match.params`, so it's expecting at least a `match` prop. Once you address and fix the props issue you'll next hit an issue with the `useHistory` hook and a missing routing context.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese I checked that as well. I have edited question at the end. could you please have a look?

Comment: ya @jonrsharpe I am very new. been forced to work when I know nothing much about this tech. thats why I am struggling

Comment: It's ok to be new, but you need to _learn the tech_. Just guessing random syntax, being surprised by errors then dumping it on SO isn't a productive way of working. Run through some structured tutorials to get to grip with React and JSX basics.

Comment: sure ,thank you John . I will definetly learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `EditCertificate` component is expecting a `match` prop with a `params` property.

```
export function EditCertificate(props: any) {
  injectStyle();

  const {id} = props.match.params;
  const history = useHistory();

  ...
}
```

This `match` prop needs to be provided in the unit test. You are creating a props object so you can just spread that into `EditCertificate`. Spread the entire `props` object, not `props.match.params`, the latter only spreads the individual params.

```
describe('EditCertificate', () => {
  const props = {
    match: {
      params: {
        id: 123, // <-- props.match.params.id
      },
    },
  };

  it('should render successfully', () => {
    const { baseElement } = render(<EditCertificate {...props} />);
    expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The next issue will be a missing routing context for the `useHistory` hook. You can provide a `wrapper` for the `render` util, or simply wrap `EditCertificate` directly.

```
const RouterWrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <MemoryRouter>{children}</MemoryRouter> // *
);

...

const { baseElement } = render(
  <EditCertificate {...props} />,
  {
    wrapper: RouterWrapper
  },
);
```

or

```
const { baseElement } = render(
  <MemoryRouter>
    <EditCertificate {...props} />
  </MemoryRouter>
);
```

* `MemoryRouter` used for unit testing since there is no DOM